# it is appropriate to accept it?

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14138/how-people-in-us-and-uk-think-about-selling-weapons-to-saudi-arabia) I ask "Is there a poll on *How people in US and UK think about  selling weapons to Saudi-Arabia?*" Thomas Hollis answers " As far as I can tell there is no poll..." . I am not sure if the answer is true, but assume that it is true. Then:
I wonder if it is appropriate to accept it. In fact if I accept it,  it has  two disadvantages; regarding the fact that "someday maybe *a poll happen*":

- the question will excluded from those questions that don't have an accepted answer (result: less attention).
- if *a poll happen* and one post another answer, then i should take the acceptation back (?).

Comment: Please clarify - Did the answer actually show meaningful evidence that there is no such poll, or merely said "no" without any evidence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd be more concerned with the correctness of the answer(which is up to you to evaluate) than with the possibility that it might eventually be rendered invalid.

Everyone can see the date that a question and answer was posted on, so future visitors should be able to consume the answer in that context.

If you still want more/better answers, then you don't need to accept an answer at all.

If someone posts a better answer, there's no problem with un-accepting it, and accepting the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to prove a negative. So the only answer we can *know* to be correct would be one pointing to a poll. Any other answer might be helpful, but can not be proven to be correct.

But has the author of the answer convinced you that they did thorough research to find such a poll and didn't find one? Do you believe them and feel smarter now?

If so, you can accept the answer.

But if you don't feel convinced yet, you might leave the question unaccepted.